# How can one variable show difference between samples, when the previous didn't? ( according to t-test)

Tags: r, normal-distribution, variance, t-test

I don't have Statistics background, and I'm trying to learn and perform some tests. I work in oligonucleotide purification, and I have two machines for that purpose. They should release the exact same amount of reagents in the purification columns, but they don't. I want to test if the differences in the amounts of reagents are statistically significant. I also want to know if this difference affect the optical density (OD) and the purity of the purified oligos.

I've proceeded like this:

1 - Got the amounts of reagents of machine A (sempla A) and machine b (sample B). Sample size is 9 each machine, can't get more.

2 - I tested each sample for normality (p-value = 0.7553 and p-value = 0.4985) 
and I tested the variances (F = 0.8649, num df = 8, denom df = 8, p-value = 0.8424)

3 - as they are both normal and they don't have different variances, I've performed t-test: t = 1.4519, df = 16, p-value = 0.1659

Then, the important thing: to test if the D.O. and purity of the purified oligos are different according to the machine.

1 - I have 7 oligos purified in each machine. The data is normally distributed  for both OD and purity of both machines (I performed one shapiro-wilk test for each sample of both variables and all p-values are greater than 0.05)

2 - Their variances are not different
(F = 0.63086, num df = 6, denom df = 6, p-value = 0.5899 for OD and
F = 1.0323, num df = 6, denom df = 6, p-value = 0.9702)

3 - T Test showed no differences for OD (t = -1.1447, df = 12, p-value = 0.2747) and some difference for purity between machines ( t = 2.8591, df = 12, p-value = 0.01438)

So I've concluded that there are no significative differences in reagent amounts, but oligos come out of the machine with differences in purity, although no differences in OD were detected.

Now, I came up with all this by reading posts and articles at internet and I'm very insecure about this data.  Are my conclusions right according to the tests and data?  Do I have sample sizes big enough for this tests?
I'm surprised with no difference in t-test in reagent amounts because the amounts of reagents are visually really different, at least when I see then in such a small purification column. But that's ok... it is what it is. But **can I perform the tests for oligos coming out of these machines even when there is no significative differences in the reagent amounts? I mean... I can't understand... there is no difference in reagent amounts... but there is difference in purity of oligos? How is that?**
Any pieces of advices?

Comment: Are there multiple different output measurements from each machine measuring different things?  If so, you have a multivariate problem and the Hotelling T-test might be appropriate.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand your question... The machines release in the columns 5 different reagents, some of then go more than once... But every time I run the purification, reagent releases one to nine go in the same amount... I mean.. the release one is always 1.3ml in machine A and 0.9 in machine B, and so on...